# How to parse the data from a webRTC stream?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webrtc

I am trying to get into the core of the webRTC stream an access the raw data that is coming into the client. I am in react-native and am creating the stream as such:

```
  if (!stream) {
      (async () => {
        const availableDevices = await mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
        const {deviceId: sourceId} = availableDevices.find(
          // once we get the stream we can just call .switchCamera() on the track to switch without re-negotiating
          // ref: https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc#mediastreamtrackprototype_switchcamera
          device => device.kind === 'videoinput' && device.facing === 'front',
        );
        const streamBuffer = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          video: {
            mandatory: {
              // Provide your own width, height and frame rate here
              minWidth: 500,
              minHeight: 300,
              minFrameRate: 30,
            },
            facingMode: 'user',
            optional: [{sourceId}],
          },
        });

        setStream(streamBuffer);
      })();
    }
```

This streamBuffer that is coming in is a URL, example: 52815B95-4406-493F-8904-0BA74887550C.
I have yet to find a way to actually access the data behind this url. I know that in reactJS, they send the url to a video element and that parses the data and spits out a jpeg image. I am trying to implement my own version of that parsing. However, I can't seem to find a way to even access the bit data that is coming into through the stream. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Since it's a stream you should add handlers on the stream for various events. Try to add the following: `streamBuffer.on('data', (chunk) => { /* do something */ });`. `data` is a common event on a stream and is emitted whenever there is new chunk of data available for processing.

Comment: Throws the error -> null is not an object evaluating stream.on. 

I see that you are trying to treat the stream like a socket event, but it is just a url identifier. In this case, stream === 52815B95-4406-493F-8904-0BA74887550C

I want to know how to access the data in that url identifier

Comment: If you refer to MDN docs on `getUserMedia` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia you will see that the return type is a `MediaStream`. `MediaStream` interface have 4 events (2 are deprecated): `addtrack` and `removetrack`. For reference on `MediaStream` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream

Comment: With regards to those events they are all throwing errors that null is not an object. This is react native fyi not pure react js and is rendering on an iPhone. Logging the data from stream.getVideoTracks() -> [{"_enabled": true, "id": "651A32F7-6D6A-47F4-A9FB-1DA6A78D4050", "kind": "video", "label": "651A32F7-6D6A-47F4-A9FB-1DA6A78D4050", "muted": false, "readonly": true, "readyState": "live", "remote": false}]

Comment: Is there another way to access incoming data?